# How to do mutual comparison after group by in a SQL query?

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have a table `Information` which is something like this:

```
ID    From     To        Product          Date  
1         A         B          ProdA         2012-10-01  
2         A         B          ProdA         2012-10-13  
3         A         B          ProdB         2012-10-17  
4         A         B          ProdC         2012-10-18  
5         A         C          ProdB         2012-10-02  
6         A         C          ProdC         2012-10-04  
7         A         C          ProdD         2012-10-12  
8         A         C          ProdE         2012-10-14  
9         A         D          ProdA         2012-10-11  
10       A         D          ProdA         2012-10-14
```

Let's call the combination of From and To a relationship. So (A,B) and (A, C) are relationships.
What I need to do is to find those relationships sending/receiving **different** products within a week time period. So in the above example the query is supposed to return:

```
A    B
A    C
```

since these rows match:

```
2         A         B          ProdA         2012-10-13  
3         A         B          ProdB         2012-10-17  
4         A         B          ProdC         2012-10-18  

5         A         C          ProdB         2012-10-02  
6         A         C          ProdC         2012-10-04  

7         A         C          ProdD         2012-10-12  
8         A         C          ProdE         2012-10-14
```

I know I should start from `SELECT ID, From, To, Product, Date FROM Information GROUP BY From, To` but I have no idea what's next. Any help please?

Comment: It's quite a bad idea to call a field `From` in a database ;) By the way, what does "within a week time period" mean ? This will be "hard written" in the query, or the query has to get this info ? Is this from sunday to sunday ?

Comment: @RaphaëlAlthaus Well that's not the real table. I was just too lazy to type the full name "SendFrom". :) Also the data were also fake. The time period could be hard written since the query is dynamically created by script so it doesn't matter: it could be 7, 15 whatever

Answer (score 1, accepted):

something like this perhaps:

```
declare @t table(id int identity(1,1), [from] char default 'A', [to] char, product char(5), date date)
-- populating testdata works with sql server 2008+
insert @t ([to],product, date) values
('B','ProdA','2012-10-01'),('B','ProdA','2012-10-13'),
('B','ProdB','2012-10-17'),('B','ProdC','2012-10-18'),
('C','ProdB','2012-10-02'),('C','ProdC','2012-10-04'),
('C','ProdD','2012-10-12'),('C','ProdE','2012-10-14'),
('D','ProdA','2012-10-11'),('D','ProdA','2012-10-14')


select * from @t t where exists 
(select 1 from @t where t.[from] = [from] and t.[to] = [to] and 
t.product <> product and t.date between dateadd(day, -7, date) and 
dateadd(day, 7, date))
```

Answer (score 1):

```
select Distinct [From],[TO],year([Date]) as y ,datepart(wk,[Date]) as w
into #tmp
From Tablex

Select t1.*
from #tmp t1
Join #tmp t2 on t1.From=t2.From and t1.y=t2.y and t1.w=t2.y and t1.to<>t2.to
 Drop table #tmp
```